# How to return JSON data in separate li elements

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to map through the below json file and display the 'list' array in separate `<li>` elements on the page but the entire list array just displays in one `<li>` element altogether. Is there a way to separate them into their own `<li>` elements?

Here is what the 'blog' JSON file looks like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "This is a title",
    "list": [
      "hello test 1",
      "hello test 2",
      "hello test 3"
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is how I'm displaying them in React:

```
<div>
  {Blog.map((blogDetail, index) => {
     return <li>{blogDetail.list}</li>
  })}
</div>
```

Comment: well, your blog object is an array, and you're mapping over it to produce one LI per blog. If you wanted to produce one li per item in each blog's list, that's a nested level you'd need to also iterate over.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div>
  {Blog.map((blogDetail, index) => {
     return (
       <>
       {blogDetail.list.map((each) => {
          return <li>{each}</li>
        })}
       </>
     )
  })}
</div>
```